# Why cant my pandas_datareader pull all the data?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to lookup 30 ticker names that are listed in a CSV file, and use pandas_datareader to pull their respective price data. However, the DataReader only returns 10-15 tickers' data and is not very consistent. (i don't think its an issue with the tickers listed in the CSV per se)

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

I'm quite new and am not sure if the below message has any relevance to my problem:

> FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.

```py
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime as dt
    import csv
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import style
    import numpy as np


    style.use('ggplot')

    end = dt.datetime.today()
    start = dt.date(end.year - 10, 1, 1)

    tickerCsv = open('STI constituents.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(tickerCsv)
    tickers = {rows[0] for rows in reader}

    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for ticker in tickers:
        df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
        df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker}, inplace=True)
        df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')
        print(main_df)

        main_df.to_csv('sti_joined.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving:

`main_df.to_csv('sti_joined.csv')` out of the `for` loop

Comment: Thanks dexter, that doesn't work unfortunately - no CSV is generated, although i'm also wondering why too.

Comment: debug the output of `outer join`